# Angular2 barrels. Use index.ts within the same folder

Tags: angular

RC5. I've created index.ts in my `"folder1"` folder which exports some classes.
Exporting from it in the component located in "folder2" `export {...} from '../folder1';` works fine.

Now, within the component located in the same "folder1" folder I can't find any way to export from the same index.ts. Something like `export {...} from './';` would make sense and actually typescript compiler is just fine with that, but when executing I'm getting some weird errors like that:

```
(index):28 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
        at new BaseException (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
        at eval (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:287:31)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:285:49)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:150:47)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:72:37)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:49:21)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:368:25)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:60068/libs/js/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:361:21)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:60068/scripts/boot.js:8:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:60068/scripts/boot.js
    Error loading http://localhost:60068/scripts/boot.js(anonymous function) @ (index):28e.invoke @ zone.min.js:1e.run @ zone.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ zone.min.js:1e.invokeTask @ zone.min.js:1e.runTask @ zone.min.js:1a @ zone.min.js:1invoke @ zone.min.js:1
```